# Ambiguous result with char and toupper

Tags: c, char, implicit-conversion, literals, toupper

How does 'ab' was converted to 24930 when stored in char?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    char c = 'ab';
    c = toupper(c);
    printf("%c", c);
    return 0;
}
```

**GCC compiler warning : Overflow in conversion from 'int' to 'char' changes value from '24930' to '98'**

> Output : B

If possible please explain how char handled the multiple characters here.

Comment: what is ambiguous here?

Comment: Please explain how it's working?

Comment: Check the compiler manual - this is implementation-defined and each compiler makes a choice and documents what it does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the C Standard (6.4.4.4 Character constants)

> 10 **An integer character constant has type int.** The value of an
> integer character constant containing a single character that maps to
> a single-byte execution character is the numerical value of the
> representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer.
> **The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g., 'ab'), or containing a character or escape sequence
> that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is
> implementation-defined.**

So this character constant 'ab' is stored as an object of the type `int`. Then it is assigned to ab object of the type `char` like in this declaration

```
char c = 'ab';
```

then the least significant byte of the object of the type `int` is used to initialize the object `c`. It seems in your case the character `'b'` was stored in this least significant byte and was assigned to the object `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Your characters are stored into 4 bytes on the right side. 24930 = 0x6162 equivalent to 0x61 'a' and 0x62 'b' = 'ab'

98 is your 'b', 0x62 in hexa, 98 in decimal, check with `man ascii`. Because of the overflow, and the fact that your system works in little endian, your 2 chars are stored on 4 bytes like this:

```
0x62 0x61 0x00 0x00
```

Because only one char is supposed to be assigned to c (sizeof char is equal to 1 byte, with a max limit of 256 bits), it truncates and keep only the first byte, your 'b'.

You can test it easily with char c = 'abcd' it will print 'D'.

Comment: Thanks you so much. Can you share some resources to learn more about underlying principles and how to gain understanding like you have?

Comment: You're welcome Naman! read books, tutorials, blogs, stackoverflow top 200 answers, and github. I made a small guide if you have time but beware it has not yet been proof-read https://github.com/agavrel/42_CheatSheet I still dont know as much as many here...

Answer (score 0):

A conforming `char c` holds a single character... multiple characters require `char *string` and you need to iterate through the string, eg something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cype.h>      // Needed for toupper()

int main()
{
    char *mystring = "ab\0";  // Null terminate
    char *mychar   = mystring;

    while ( *mychar != '\0' )
    {
      char c = toupper( *mychar );
      printf( "%c", c );
      mychar++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As an aside, `toupper()` returns an `int`, so there is an implicit type conversion there.